# Windows Batch to Overwrite Existing files in folder and subfolders

Tags: file, batch-file, replace, cmd

I am not good in this. I really need help.

I have searched a lot but no luck.

I want to create empty files and replace existing in a folder and its subfolders.

From my search, I could find how to make a batch to delete.

```
set folder="test"
cd /d %folder%
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
```

However, I want to replace the files with empty one, I tried this:

```
set folder="test"
cd /d %folder%
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (echo. 2>"%%i")
```

But it is not working. I need this to replace all my existing files so after delete it should not be recovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better quote the whole set command and use always quotes:

```
set "folder=x:\test"
cd /d "%folder%" ||(pause&Goto :Eof)
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b/A-D') do Type Nul >"%%i"
```

To not by mistake clear the current folder I added the `||(pause&Goto :Eof)` in case the cd didn't work. This is a conditional execution on fail of the previous command

Comment: Sorry, nothing is happening

Comment: You did change the `x:\test` to a path  on your system you want to null out? And the files do have a size other than zero?

Comment: I changed to c:\test. and yes the files do have a size other than zero.

Comment: I got it. it changes only the files in the main directory what about all child folders (sub-directories)

Comment: Add `/s` to the dir options.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks :)